# How do I create dynamic form for users to create and populate html select elements?

Tags: reactjs

Scenario: building an eCommerce type application in react. A feature is allowing merchants to create product listings. Now most products will have options (sizes, colors, etc.) and merchants should be able to add them to the listing. I am having trouble adding this part to the form as it needs to be dynamic because we don't know many options a merchant wants to add to a product listing, nor do we know how many values the option will take.

A filled array of options should look something like this before being sent to server:

```
const options = [
option1: 
  {
   name: 'Size',
   values: ['small', 'medium', 'large']
  },
option2: 
  {
   name: 'Color',
   values: ['blue', 'black', 'white', 'tan']
  },
]
```

I just don't know how to go about constructing the UI and the logic to able this feature.

Comment: It could be more than just size and color. Essentially users should be able to create select elements(title and values). @NaikJavaid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code helps you.

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-05-w61vj4)

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([
{
  name: "Size",
  values: ["small", "medium", "large"]
},
{
  name: "Color",
  values: ["blue", "black", "white", "tan"]
}])

const [optionName, setOptionName] = useState("")
const [optionVal, setOptionVal] = useState([])

// console.log("name : ", { name: optionName });
// console.log("val : ", { values: optionVal });

const handleSubmit = () => {
const newOpt = {
  name: optionName,
  values: optionVal
};
// console.log(newOpt);

setOptions([...options, newOpt]);};
console.log("option is ", options);



 return (
<>
  <div>
    <input
      id="optionName"
      type="text"
      onBlur={(e) => setOptionName(e.target.value)}
    />
    <br />
    <input
      id="optionVal"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Use , to splite values"
      onBlur={(e) => {
        const data = e.target.value;
        setOptionVal(data.split(","));
      }}
    />
    <br />
    <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
      Submit form
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    {options.map((item, i) => (
      <>
        <div>{item.name}</div>
        <div>
          {item.values.map((val) => (
            <div>{val}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <br />
      </>
    ))}
  </div>
</>);
```